# Caret in transparent JTextPane

Tags: java, swing

I have a transparent, editable JTextPane in a program I'm writing (to allow a background to show through), and everything works pretty well, except for the text caret.

The caret itself acts normally, but every time it's drawn, it breaks the transparency of the area right behind it, as seen in the image:

[image]

Is there any way to make the background of the caret transparent without repainting the whole frame? `DefaultCaret` doesn't have a `setOpaque()` method, so I'm not quite sure how to go about this.

Thanks!

EDIT: I can't answer my own question yet, but I ended up writing an SSCCE that works perfectly, so there is definitely something else wrong with my program. For future reference, this is the (working) code I wrote:

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

class TransparentScrollPane extends JScrollPane {
    public TransparentScrollPane(Component view) {
        super(view);        
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(540,480));
        this.setOpaque(false);
        this.viewport.setOpaque(false);
        this.setBorder(null);
    }
}

public class TextPaneExample extends JTextPane {

    public TextPaneExample()
    {
        super();
        this.setOpaque(false);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(new Color(255,255,255,128));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(640, 480);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(new Color(255,128,255));

        TextPaneExample textPane = new TextPaneExample();
        TransparentScrollPane scroller = new 
                TransparentScrollPane(textPane);
        textPane.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255,128));

        frame.add(panel);

        panel.add(scroller,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you put some code that would be great?

Comment: To reproduce your problem, we would have to code by hand. As you already have coded, you just could add your done code to your question, so that we can quickly look into the issue. Please, post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I originally wrote the program in JRuby, so I spent a little while just now writing up a SSCCE...which works perfectly. There's probably something else wrong with my code that has nothing to do with JTextPane, so I'll go through it again. Thanks for helping, and sorry for the hassle.

Answer (score 1):

See [Backgrounds With Transparency](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for the problem and a couple of solutions.

Basically you can just use:

```
panel.add( new AlphaContainer(componentWithTransparency) );
```

For your first question you get one free answer :) Future questions should include a proper `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem.